# Field Service Lightning - some objects not visible in dataloader

Tags: standard-objects, field-service-lightning, third-party

I am trying to use dataloader.io to load data into a standard Field Service Lightning object - "Product Request". However I cannot see this object in the available objects for dataloader.

I'm also trying to use Formyoula to map to FSL objects and am having the same problem -- some objects are missing.

**Things I have already checked:**

1. My System Admin profile has CRED on the objects
2. My System Admin profile has read/write permissions for field-level security
3. My User has the has the "Field Service Standard" license which is supposed to grant modify all access to the Objects I need
4. My System Admin profile has the "Modify All" setting

What am I missing? Why can I not see some FSL standard objects in a 3rd party connected app?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try with below checkbox **Show all Salesforce object**? sometimes it may help you to resolve your issue.

[image]

Comment: thanks that actually worked! However, I'm still unable to see the objects in Formyoula. Is there some sort of Salesforce setting that I have to choose to allow the Object to be retrieved by a 3rd party app?

Comment: I don't have FSL on my test org. However, can you please check on the object that you try to add formula has a relationship with FSL objects. At the formula, we can not retrieve object unless if they are not related directly or indirectly.

Comment: actually I meant "Formyoula", its a form building & survey tool that I'm integrating with Salesforce and FSL --> http://www.formyoula.com/

Comment: Sorry Justin,, I won't be able to help you with that,,,

Comment: Do you know why the dataloader is such a poor tool? It's objectively terrible software.

Comment: No idea,, most of my work requirement could be achieved with data Loader